# Laravel how to manage home of social networks

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, social-networking, facebook-wall

I would ask you how to handle a home page into a social network after login procedure. Thanks for reply

Comment: did you mean social login?

Comment: I think eh refers to the aftermath of signing in though Facebook, Twitter, Stack Overflow etc... and how to handle it? Try this maybe? [Facebook LoginTutorial](https://appdividend.com/2017/07/12/laravel-facebook-login/)

Comment: Thanks guys. I like very much this tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you initialize the project through Composer or manually?

However: 
home VIEW:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="h-20"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @include('widgets.sidebar')
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">
            <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                @include('widgets.suggested_people')
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @include('widgets.wall')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
<script type="text/javascript">
    WALL_ACTIVE = true;
    fetchPost(0,0,0,10,-1,-1,'initialize');
</script>
@endsection
```

home CONTROLLER:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Library\IPAPI;
use App\Library\sHelper;
use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\Hobby;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User; 
use DB;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $wall = [
        'new_post_group_id' => 0
    ];
    return view('home', compact('user', 'wall'));
}
public function search(Request $request){
    $s = $request->input('s');
    if (empty($s)) return redirect('/');
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = Post::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
        ->where(function($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('users.private', 0)->orWhere(function($query) use ($user){
                $query->whereExists(function ($query) use($user){
                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                        ->from('user_following')
                        ->whereRaw('user_following.following_user_id = users.id and user_following.follower_user_id = '.$user->id);
                });
            })->orWhere(function($query) use ($user){
                $query->where('users.private', 1)->where('users.id', $user->id);
            });
        })->where('posts.content', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')->where('posts.group_id', 0)
        ->groupBy('posts.id')->select('posts.*')->orderBy('posts.id', 'DESC')->get();
    $comment_count = 2;
    $users = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')->orWhere('username', 'like', '%'.$s.'%')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
    return view('search', compact('users', 'posts', 'user', 'comment_count'));
}
}
```

SOURCE :  https://github.com/lvntayn/laravel-social-network

it's a complete social network using Laravel, probably you will find much more than you need.

I hope it helps